# Variable does not exist in relationship SOQL

Tags: soql, relationships

I tried the following SOQL and tried to use the ProductCode but getting the error as given below.

```
for(PriceBookEntry pbe: [Select p.UseStandardPrice, p.UnitPrice, p.ProductCode, p.Product2Id, p.Pricebook2Id, p.Name, p.Id From PricebookEntry p where p.ProductCode in : lstProdCode]) {
    mapPbe.put(p.ProductCode,pbe);
}
```

> Compilation error: Variable does not exist: p.ProductCode

Any suggestions please. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When iterating through your list you are using `p.ProductCode` to access the field but your loop variable is called `pbe`.

You should use `pbe.ProductCode` instead.

Altenatively you can take the ProductCode value from the [`Product2`](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_product2.htm) record which is related to your [`PricebookEntry`](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_pricebookentry.htm). Although there is no real advantage to using this approach.

If you want to do it, then change the following:

```
p.ProductCode
```

To this, in both your query and when you add to your map:

```
p.Product2.ProductCode
```

Comment: Sometimes you just need an another set of eyes ;)

Comment: @Alex you first reply has worked fine for me. If you rollback i will mark that as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @BaskaranS I've edited this answer to include my other one, the previous answer contained some false statements, plus I believe this is the better answer as there is no advantage to using `Product2.ProductCode` as the `ProductCode` field on `PricebookEntry` will always contain the same value.